# Share on facebook page throwing an error

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sharer, android-facebook

When I'm sharing on Facebook page, getting following error :

**(#100) Only owners of the URL have the ability to specify the picture, name, thumbnail or description params.**

It was working fine 5-10 days ago. When searched I found following on [Facebook developer site link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/page/feed#custom-image) :

> "As of November 7, 2017, link customization is available however the
>   link must be owned by the posting page and a page access token is
>   required. To verify ownership, check the
>   ownership_permissions{can_customize_link_posts} field on the URL node.
>   See our Link Ownership Guide for more information. For versions 2.10
>   and lower, picture, name, thumbnail, and description are deprecated.
>   caption is deprecated for all versions."

Any help would be appreciated!

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(shareUrl))
            .build();

new ShareApi(content).share(new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            shareCallback.onSuccess(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            shareCallback.onCancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            shareCallback.onError(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: how exactly are you trying to share? please include your code.

Comment: @luschn : I edited my question, please have a look!

Comment: ok, so you really only try to share the url, no additional parameters?

Comment: @luschn : Yes we are sharing only url

Answer (score 5):

From what I know this is a very recent change to the facebook api.
It requires the page editors to add a metatag with the page id.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties?hc_location=ufi

On that page please look for `fb:pages`

Here's the description of `fb:pages`

> One or more Facebook Page IDs that are associated with a URL in order
>   to enable link editing and instant article publishing.

In short you need to add `<meta property="fb:pages" content="PAGE_ID">` in order to edit the share content.

Answer (score 2):

i have implemented it by using ShareDialog here is the code

```
CallbackManager callbackManager;
ShareDialog shareDialog;
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

                }
            });
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                            .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
                                    .build())
                            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(shareUrl))
                            .build();
                    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
                }
```

i hope it can help you